# Angular mat-select not displaying zone name on edit

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

i'm using angular mat-select to display a list from WebAPI (zone table)...it display correct what i need (zone object Zoneid, Zname ). on submit i save the id (witch is foreign key on operation table)... my problem, when i select an operation object from mat-table list to edit, the form load the object and set controls (input text) with all values that i need to display except mat-select component it display nothing (i want to display zone name and when i submit i save just the zone id)..can you help me to reach my goal this is my code:

## form html file

```
 <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select formControlName="Zname"  placeholder="Zone" >
                <mat-option>None</mat-option>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let zone of zoneList" >
                <mat-option value="{{zone.ZoneID}}" >{{zone.Zname}}</mat-option>
                </ng-container>
            </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

## service file

```
........

populateForm(Operation) {

 this.form.setValue(Operation);

}
```

## operations list html file

```
  <div class="search-div" lan="ar" dir="rtl">
    <button mat-raised-button  (click)="onCreate()">
      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>New Operation
    </button>
    <mat-form-field class="search-form-field" floatLabel="never">
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchKey" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="applyFilter()">
      <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" *ngIf="searchKey"  (click)="onSearchClear()">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="mat-elevation-z8" lan="ar" dir="rtl">
    <mat-table [dataSource]="listData"  matSort>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="TransID" [style.display]="'none'">
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.TransID}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="TransNo">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header>xxxx</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.TransNo}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="RequestDate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header>xxxxx</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.RequestDate | date: "dd/MM/yyyy" }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Seller">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>xxxxx</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Seller}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Buyer">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>xxxxx</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Buyer}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="ZoneID" [style.display]="'none'">
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.ZoneID}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Gouvernorat">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>xxxxx</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Gouv}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Zname">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>zone</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Zname}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="LOT">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>xxxx</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.LOT}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="TransType" >
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>xxxx</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.TransType}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Agent"  [style.display]="'none'">
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Agent}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Statut">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>xxxxx</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Statut}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="onEdit(row)"><mat-icon>launch</mat-icon></button>
          <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="onDelete(row.TransID)"><mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon></button>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="loading">
        <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
          ...جاري تحميل البيانات 
        </mat-footer-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="noData">
        <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
          ...لا يوجد بيانات
        </mat-footer-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
      <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['loading']" [ngClass]="{'hide':listData!=null}"></mat-footer-row>
      <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noData']" [ngClass]="{'hide':!(listData!=null && listData.data.length==0)}"></mat-footer-row>
    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100, 250]" [pageSize]="25" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

## my sql tables

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S3BA.png
```

## component of operation list

```
export class OperationsHistoryComponent implements OnInit {

 
  listData:any; 
  
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['TransNo','RequestDate','Seller','Buyer','TransType','Gouvernorat','Zname','LOT','Statut','actions'];
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  searchKey: string;
  

  constructor(private service: OperationService,
              private dialog: MatDialog,
              public notificationService: NotificationService,
              public dialogService: DialogService) 
  {  
   
  }

  ngOnInit() {

      this.service.getOperationsList().subscribe(data => {
        
                   this.listData = new MatTableDataSource();
                   this.listData.data = data;

                    this.listData.sort = this.sort;
                    this.listData.paginator = this.paginator;
             
               });

       
              }


  onEdit(row){

    this.service.populateForm(row);
  
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "60%";
    this.dialog.open(OperationComponent,dialogConfig);
  }

 

}
```

Comment: please add more details like the function call in HTML eg: onEdit

Comment: this is my mat-table

Comment: your select is empty ?

Comment: regardless  my source code...how can we achieve this on angular...can any one told me please